# Making the body of a function use a mock of an object

Tags: ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, stripe-payments

I have the following method in a controller:

```
def webhook
    data_json = JSON.parse(request.body.read) # it comes from the test, it's OK
    event = Stripe::Event.retrieve(data_json[:id]) # it's not OK, it's a real request to Stripe
    stripe_cust_id = event.data.object.customer
    user = User.where(stripe_customer_id: stripe_cust_id)
    #.....
```

In a spec file I create a mock for `event` and then make a post request to `webhook` in a test. I'm not allowed to change the body or signature of `webhook` because I'm testing it. So how do I make it use the mock I create?

```
describe '#webhook' do
    it 'something' do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      event = StripeMock.mock_webhook_event('invoice.payment_succeeded')
      post(:webhook, event.to_json)

      #error because webhook makes a real request to Stripe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mock(Stripe::Event).retrieve(any) do
  event
end
```

That should return `event` from any call to `retrieve` on `Stripe::Event`. Works with `rr`.

Comment: you didn't understand the question.

Comment: Then you should try to explain it better, in my humble opinion, because I agree with @Satya on answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is only about external requests, you can try something like [Vcr](https://rubygems.org/gems/vcr) or [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to mock the responce.